# Mapping two integers to one: deriving formula

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have an interesting puzzle: Given two non-negative integers, let's call them $x$ and $y$, work out a formula for $z$ as shown in the table below:

```
          x
 ___|_0__1__2__3__4_...
  0 | 0  1  3  6 10 
  1 | 2  4  7 11 16
y 2 | 5  8 12 17 23 ... 
  3 | 9 13 18 24 31
  4 |14 19 25 32 40
 ...|20 26 33 41 50
         ...
```

where $z$ is the number in the middle. You should see a pattern if you look along the (positive) diagonals. This question is about the next part of this puzzle, so I will show a basic formula for $z$ below. If you want to solve this yourself, look away now. Seriously, I think you should try solving it yourself. As you're still reading, here's the formula:

> $$\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y = z$$
>  When $y = 0$, $z$ is the $x$th triangular number. Following a line down and to the left shows a similar number, just incremented by one. So what if we tried the $x+y$th triangular number? It's close, but we still need it increasing by one as it goes down. So we add $y$ onto the $x+y$th triangular number, giving the result.

Knowing that $x$, $y$ and $z$ will always be non-negative integers, and knowing that for each unique $x$ and $y$, there is only one $z$, and that for each unique $z$, there is only one pair of $x$ and $y$, surely it's possible to calculate $x$ and $y$ given only $z$.

That is, to create a formula for $x$ in terms of $z$, and to create a formula for $y$ in terms of $z$. I know it's possible, and I've tried it, but I keep hitting things that I don't know how to do. So I thought I'd publish the problem, and learn from it at the same time.

Please answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of the Cantor diagonalization.

See [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) for more information.

Cantor used it to show that $\mathbb{N}^2$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$.

In theoretical computer science it is used to show that register machines
with $n$ arguments can be modeled by register machines with one argument, by iteratively encoding and decoding the $n$ arguments into one argument.

Comment: Should I delete the question? It's probably a duplicate.

Comment: No, in this case this post will be locked and marked as duplicate sooner or later. Great you liked this problem and started going for the inverse.

Comment: Ok. I think I've worked out how to solve it now, after a couple of weeks of trying. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @mvw, one call them pairing or diagonalizing functions. They can be given by polynomials:
$$<x,y> = ((x+y)^2+x+3y)/2$$ or 
$$<x,y> = ((x+y)^2+3x+y)/2).$$
Other types of pairing exist, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

with some [Matlab code](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44253-three-different-bijections-or-pairing-functions-between-n-and-n%5E2--including-cantor-polynomials-). [Some remarks on the Cantor pairing function](http://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/view/14) may provide you with additional details.